# Error java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NO_INTS

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, amazon-kinesis

Getting the below error when running spark streaming application to fetch the data from kinesis.

```
Exception in thread "Kinesis Receiver 0" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NO_INTS
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.cbor.CBORParser.<init>(CBORParser.java:285)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.cbor.CBORParserBootstrapper.constructParser(CBORParserBootstrapper.java:91)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.cbor.CBORFactory._createParser(CBORFactory.java:392)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.cbor.CBORFactory.createParser(CBORFactory.java:308)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.cbor.CBORFactory.createParser(CBORFactory.java:295)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.cbor.CBORFactory.createParser(CBORFactory.java:26)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:2294)
        at com.amazonaws.protocol.json.JsonContent.parseJsonContent(JsonContent.java:72)
        at com.amazonaws.protocol.json.JsonContent.<init>(JsonContent.java:64)
        at com.amazonaws.protocol.json.JsonContent.createJsonContent(JsonContent.java:54)
        at com.amazonaws.http.JsonErrorResponseHandler.handle(JsonErrorResponseHandler.java:89)
        at com.amazonaws.http.JsonErrorResponseHandler.handle(JsonErrorResponseHandler.java:40)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AwsErrorResponseHandler.handleAse(AwsErrorResponseHandler.java:53)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AwsErrorResponseHandler.handle(AwsErrorResponseHandler.java:41)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AwsErrorResponseHandler.handle(AwsErrorResponseHandler.java:26)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1781)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleServiceErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1383)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1359)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1139)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:796)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:764)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:738)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:698)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:680)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:544)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:524)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.doInvoke(AmazonKinesisClient.java:2809)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.invoke(AmazonKinesisClient.java:2776)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.invoke(AmazonKinesisClient.java:2765)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.executeListShards(AmazonKinesisClient.java:1557)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.listShards(AmazonKinesisClient.java:1528)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.proxies.KinesisProxy.listShards(KinesisProxy.java:325)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.proxies.KinesisProxy.getShardList(KinesisProxy.java:440)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.KinesisShardSyncer.getShardList(KinesisShardSyncer.java:349)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.KinesisShardSyncer.syncShardLeases(KinesisShardSyncer.java:159)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.KinesisShardSyncer.checkAndCreateLeasesForNewShards(KinesisShardSyncer.java:112)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.ShardSyncTask.call(ShardSyncTask.java:84)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.MetricsCollectingTaskDecorator.call(MetricsCollectingTaskDecorator.java:49)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.Worker.initialize(Worker.java:683)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.Worker.run(Worker.java:614)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisReceiver$$anon$1.run(KinesisReceiver.scala:191)
```

Here is the command that was executed:

```
spark-submit --jars spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.11-2.4.5.jar,amazon-kinesis-client-1.13.2.jar,aws-java-sdk-kinesis-1.11.745.jar,aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.745.jar,aws-java-sdk-sts-1.11.745.jar,aws-java-sdk-1.11.745.jar,aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.745.jar,aws-java-sdk-cloudwatch-1.11.745.jar,jackson-core-2.9.8.jar,jackson-dataformat-cbor-2.9.8.jar,jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar  snowplow_spark/src/main.py
```

And code is very basic:

```
kinesisStream = KinesisUtils.createStream(
        ssc, kinesisAppName=appName, streamName=streamName, endpointUrl=endpointUrl,
        regionName=regionName, initialPositionInStream=InitialPositionInStream.LATEST,
        checkpointInterval=10)
```

I have been stuck on this since days and have no idea what to do. I know that somewhere the jackson version is not matching in spark and aws-sdk but dont know which one to put in --jars.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you have it resolved already, but https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-25455 issue is related to that. I ran into same issue. I got it to work with the below dependency in pom.xml. Also all the aws libraries are of 2.16.0 version in my project. Hope this helps.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-cbor</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.7</version>
</dependency>
```